# Mounting Kubernetes config map as single file returns error: "caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown"

Tags: kubernetes

This is my pod:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/configs/config.tmpl
      name: config-main
      readOnly: true
      subPath: config.tmpl
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: config-main
    name: config-main
```

This is my config map:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-main
data:
  config.tmpl: |
        # here goes my config content
```

This produces the following error:

> Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim: OCI
> runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container
> process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused:
> rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting
> "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/dc66ebd1-90ef-4c25-bb69-4b3329f61a5a/volume-subpaths/config-main/podname/1"
> to rootfs at "/etc/configs/config.tmpl" caused: mount through procfd:
> not a directory: unknown

The container has pre-existing `/etc/configs/config.tmpl` file that I want to override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it work:

1. `mountPath` must be a directory
2. using `subPath` didn't work for me, anyway [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically) says "using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume mount will not receive ConfigMap updates", which isn't an option for me

so I guess you can't mount a single file, you always mount a directory but then you can optionally limit which files from the configmap's data you want there via `items` in a volume.

```
spec:
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/configs
      name: config-main
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: config-main
    name: config-main
```

Answer (score 3):

To mount as file instead of directory try:

```
spec:
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/configs/config.tmpl
      name: config-main
      readOnly: true
      subPath: config.tmpl
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      items:
      - key: config.tmpl
        path: config.tmpl
      name: config-main
    name: config-main
```

Comment: Now it says "MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-main" : configmap references non-existent config key: config.tmpl"

Comment: See the ConfigMap in your question, there's a key `config.tmpl` under `data` section.

Comment: yes, I know, nevertheless that's the error I get